# How to solve with this C code?

Tags: c, implementation

when i try to run the code am having problem in the output.

when the inputs s= 1, m=1 then am able to output i.e. solar and mains contactors result.

when both inputs are 0 i.e. s =0 and m = 0, then it is giving "There is no power".(correct output)

when s = 1, m = 0 it should say "There is no power". and am able to get the correct output.

when s=0, m=1, it should say "There is no power", but instead its continuing to the solar contactors information(not the correct output).

So what could be the problem can anyone explain me?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int main()
{
    bool s, m; //input parameters
    bool a, b; 
    bool p, q; 
    bool t;    //output parameters          

    printf("Enter the value of solar VMD : \n");  //scanning vmd values of solar 
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("Enter the value of Mains VMD : \n");  //scanning vmd values of Mains
    scanf("%d", &m);      

    if(s == 1,m == 1)               
    {                
        printf("Scan solar contactor : \n");  //scanning solar contactor 
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("Scan Mains contactor : \n");  //scanning mains contactor
        scanf("%d", &b);

        if(a == 1, b == 1)  //when solar & mains contactor are close
        {
            q = FALSE;
            p = TRUE;
            printf("Solar contactor and Mains contactor: %d %d", p, q);
        }
        else if(a == 0, b == 1)  //when solar contctor is open and mains is closed
        { 
            q = FALSE;
            p = TRUE;
            printf("Solar contactor and Mains contactor: %d %d", p, q);
        }
        else if(a == 1, b == 0)  //when solar contactor is closed and mains is open
        {  
            q = FALSE;
            p = TRUE;
            printf("Solar contactor and Mains contactor: %d %d", p, q);
        }      
        else if(a == 0, b == 0)  //when both solar and mains are open                    
        {
            q = FALSE;
            p = TRUE;
            printf("Solar contactor and Mains contactor: %d %d", p, q);
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Problem with contactors");
        }   
    }

    else 
    {
        printf("There is no power");
    }    

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you actually format your code so it's readable?

Comment: In addition to the formatting, could you give your question a title which actually tells us something about the question you're asking? "How to solve this with C code" could be about anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(s == 1,m == 1)
```

This code doesn't do what you think it does. Learn about [operators of the C language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B), especially [logical operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Logical_operators) and [the comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

**Update**

The other bug is that `%d` would not work with `bool`. In fact there's no `scanf` format which would. So you have to either stick to `int` (which is a perfectly good type for doing boolean operators), or write your own function to read `bool`s from a stream.

Comment: yes, i did tried using implementation of logic, but the output is "There is no power" for all the possible 4 cases.
Which is undesirable.

Comment: then check your input and your logic.

Comment: Brat, am giving the input values either logic 1 or 0.
So am sure that the inputs are not the problem.

Comment: Did you throw it into a debugger and look? Do so and check if what you're seeing matches what you think should be happening.

Comment: Use the proper logical operator. There's only one you can use. Try to figure out which one (hint: it's not the comma). Then if something doesn't work, try to figure out what else doesn't work.

Comment: Brat, i did checked now with using logic operators.
And am able to get the desired output only after changing the input parameters type to "integer".
So why not it worked with boolean algebra?

Comment: You could make it work after all. So you should have asked "why this works, and this doesn't", preferably after reducing your code to a minimal working example. The answer to *that* question is in the update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to check out which works better,
and one thing is that my inputs are digital.

Answer (score 0):

One example of a bug is the following:

```
if(s == 1,m == 1)
```

Instead of that, you probably want

```
if (s == 1 && m == 1)
```

Comment: Yes i did that && function, 
but the output is "There is no power" for all the cases (1,1), (1,0), (0,1),(0,0).
Which is not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Instead of:**                **put:**
   if(s == 1,m == 1)       - if(s == 1 && m == 1)
   if(a == 1,b == 1)       - if(a == 1 && b == 1)
   else if(a == 0, b == 1) - else if(a == 0 && b == 1)
   else if(a == 1, b == 0) - else if(a == 1 && b == 0)
   else if(a == 0, b == 0) - else if(a == 0 && b == 0)
```

---

*The logical operators && and || are used when evaluating two expressions to obtain a single relational result. The operator && corresponds with Boolean logical operation AND. This operation results true if both its two operands are true, and false otherwise. The following panel shows the result of operator && evaluating the expression a && b:*

```
 a       b      a && b
true    true    true
true    false   false
false   true    false
false   false   false
```

Comment: Thx for reply to post ddacot,
If u really dont mind, pl you once compile and run the code using the logic operators.
And, this is what i did before, assigned another bool variable t,
t = s&&m, then i have gone for, if(t == 1){execute}.
But the result is "There is no power" for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

if(s == 1,m == 1)
It's wrong
You need to wirte

if(s == 1 && m == 1)

&& this operator check if s==1 and m ==1 
if yes then condition true or goes to elseif block